# How start a new activity on button click in the alert dialog?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have created a alertdialog class in one package and i have called that as a method in another class. What i want is when the user clicks a button on the alertdialog it has to start a new activity. I don't know how to do that please guide me. Do i need to create a method in alertdialog class for button to perform an action if so how.

Alertdialog.java

```
public class Alertdialog implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int ALERT_DIALOG = 1;
    int dialog;
    Dialog dialog1;
    Context dia;
    String st;
    Button bq;
    String a;

    public Alertdialog() {

    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public Dialog customalertdialog(Context dia, int id, String r, String a,
            String b, String b1) {
        // protected Dialog onCreateDialog( ){
        // this.dialog = ALERT_DIALOG;
        this.dia = dia;
        if (id == ALERT_DIALOG) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(dia,
                    R.style.MyTheme);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.setPositiveButton(b, null)
                    .setNegativeButton(b1, null).setMessage(a).setTitle(r)
                    .create();
            DisplayMetrics metrics = alertDialog.getContext().getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics();
            final int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
                    View view = alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView()
                            .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.width = 4 * width / 5; // 80% of screen
                    layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                            new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                }
            });
            alertDialog.show();
            bq = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            bq.setBackground(dia.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.radibutton));
            Button bq1 = alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            bq1.setBackground(dia.getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.radibutton));
            if (bq != null && bq1 != null) {
                bq.setHeight(75);
                bq1.setHeight(75);

            }

        }
        return dialog1;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the context from the activity you have called the `Alertdialog` class and then use the context to startActivity(intent).

code:...

```
public class Alertdialog implements OnClickListener {
private static final int ALERT_DIALOG = 1;
int dialog;
Dialog dialog1;
Context dia;
String st;
Button bq;
String a;

private Context context; //this line

public Alertdialog(Context context) {
   this.context = context //this line
}

.....
```

then in your BUTTON_POSITIVE add:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, whereverYouWantToGo.class);
context.startActivity(i);
```

hope you got the idea.. give me a feedback whether it worked or not.

Comment: how to implement this in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code to invoke the activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectCityActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Statics.INTENT_PARAM_CITY_SEARCH_TITLE,"Choose a city");
    intent.putExtra(Statics.INTENT_PARAM_CITY_SEARCH_SUB_TITLE,"where are you leaving from");
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CITY_REQUEST);
```

Comment: also you will need to pass the context instead of "this" in the first line of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please do this in a simple way. Where you will need AlertDialogue then paste the following code

```
    AlertDialog alert_back = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentClassName.this).create();
                    alert_back.setTitle("Alert Dialog Title");
                    alert_back.setMessage("Alert Dialog Message");

                    alert_back.setButton2("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentClassName.this,DestinationClassName.class);
                startActivity(intent);
dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    alert_back.show();
```

If you would like to go this way then it will be easy .

Try this and give feedback.

Comment: how to implement in fragment

Comment: fragment or fragmentactivity ? please let me inform

Comment: Ok please wait .. first I will check and let you know

Comment: i have created a method in alertdialog class. In which i have mentioned if (yes.equalsIgnoreCase("TopUp")) {
    Topup fragment1 = new Topup();
    if (fragment1 != null) {
     FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
     fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment1).commit();
    }                         but its not working

Comment: So, would you like to open a fragment class from alertdialog ?

Comment: I will be back after 1 and half hour. It's my break time. Don't mind please.